# How to change Opencv image viewer?

Tags: opencv

I have installed OpenCV on my desktop and laptop which they have Ubuntu 14, and i have some problem with its image viewer.

First of all when i type :

```
./facedetect --cascade="/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml" --nested-cascade="/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml" --scale=1.5 [address of my image]
```

It shows my image with its image viewer , but it isn't resizabe on my desktop and it don't show control buttons at top of it on my laptop.

How can i fix these problem or can i change its image viewer ?

Comment: `it isn't resistible` You mean resizable, do you ? And what control buttons do you expect ? To control what ?

Comment: yes i do.i mean zoom button and move button.when i click on image, it close.

Comment: Hey, you do have the window "close" button on top {left|right} of the window, do you ?

Answer (score 1):

Opencv uses in many demo applications its own GUI ([highgui](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/highgui.html)), its features are limited and are platform-dependent. For example, I think that the "auto-zoom" feature that enables you to see the pixel values is available only on Windows. And, although recent versions added some Qt support to add somes features (buttons,...), the app has to be build to enable these features, and this is probably not the case in your example.

However, you can always edit the code of these apps (here, the `facedetect` app) so that it just saves the images on disk, instead of showing them on screen. Then rebuild. Or add yourself the buttons you want, see the manual.